# Group entries in Pandas data frame where rows have identical values

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a Pandas data frame where I want to group all rows that have the same values and group them by the index column.

Example:

```
data = {'Number':[5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 28],
        'Letter':['a','a','b','b','c','c'],
        'Type':['X','X','Y','Y','Z','Z']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.set_index('Number')
```

Output:

```
           Letter Type
Number            
5           a    X
10          a    X
15          b    Y
20          b    Y
25          c    Z
28          c    Z
```

My wanted output is:

```
[[5,10],[15,20],[25,28]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First idea is convert index to column and aggregate `list`:

```
print (df.reset_index().groupby(['Letter', 'Type'])['Number'].agg(list).tolist())
[[5, 10], [15, 20], [25, 28]]
```

Or you can use lambda function:

```
print (df.groupby(['Letter', 'Type']).apply(lambda x: x.index.tolist()).tolist())
[[5, 10], [15, 20], [25, 28]]
```

Comment: Thanks! Does not these solutions ignore the 'Type' column? I am looking for a solution for an arbitrary number of rows. Assume for example Type is changed to
`Type: X, X, Y, Y. Z, A`
then the wanted behavior is [[5,10],[15,20],[25],[28]].

I hope it clarifies.

Comment: @Marten - Oppss, now understand. Answer was edited.

Comment: Typo above in my comment '..arbitrary number of columns..'. So, I think what I was after was in the end something like:

`df.groupby(list(df.columns[df.columns != 'Number']))['Number'].agg(list).tolist()`

Seems to work well. Thanks!